How to extract date part from folder name and move it to another folder on hdfs using pyspark
I currently have folders and sub-folders in day-wise structure in this path '/dev/data/'
2024.03.30
   part-00001.avro
   part-00002.avro
2024.03.31
   part-00001.avro
   part-00002.avro
2024.04.01
   part-00001.avro
   part-00002.avro
2024.04.02
   part-00001.avro
   part-00002.avro

and so on.. I have avro files inside these folders.
I need to move this to another path by combining all day-wise folders into month folder.  I need the folder structure as below
2024.03
2024.04
2024.05

and so on. All the avro files should be under month folder.
I have written the below code where I'm creating extra columns and using existing date column to extract the yyyy-MM part.
day_df = spark.read.format("avro").load("path/to/dev/data")
month_df = day_df.withColumn("month", F.date_format(F.col("exit_date"),'yyyy-MM'))
month_df.write.partitionBy("month").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("path/to/dest")

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this without creating month column
